# C# SIMD-optimized code in x86

Tags: c#, x86, simd, system.numerics

System.Numerics.Vectors was recently added to the .NET Framework to add SIMD support, but it only works for x64 as far as I know. I also see it is still in active development and a new version was just released on June 27th, but there's no release notes describing the changes.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors/4.1.1

My question is: is there any way to add SIMD optimization to x86 code in C#?

So far the only way is to create a separate C++ project which can be embedded into the DLL and extracted at run-time, but that's not a pretty solution.

Comment: The SIMD optimizations require RyuJIT, which is currently only available on x86-64. If I understand correctly, there is eventually supposed to be an x86-32 version of RyuJIT, but it hasn't been released yet. Presumably there are significant stability problems, or the team responsible is focusing on something else. RyuJIT was originally a fork of the regular x86 JIT. If you need real performance, writing the code in C++ is still the only option. Even for 64-bit, these SIMD optimizations are *extremely* limited in scope.

Comment: There is just no conceivable reason for Microsoft to invest any resources in the x86 jitter.  It stopped being relevant too long ago, machine builders stopped using 32-bit processors completely and 64-bit operating systems have been ubiquitous for 10 years already.  The only drag is that VS projects templates still have the "Prefer 32-bit" option checked.  Hopefully that will end in the next release.

Comment: There are still many 3rd party components forcing to use x86, and for many project, to real benefit to using x64. However, most x86 3rd party programs have now been ported or are in the process of having a x64 option so that's getting better. When performance is so critical to require SIMD, then I do agree that there's no point in using x86... unless that's a requirement. For the code I want to write, it needs to work with both. However, still no option for using Windows Media Player x64 in .NET.

Comment: @HansPassant: that makes sense. For many programs (obviously not the one in the question), 32 bit or 64 bit makes no big difference, and 32 bit programs do run on a 64 bit Windows, but not the other way around.